# HTML で指定した画像が表示されない

Tags: html, aws-cloud9

AWS、HTMLでポートフォリオを作りたいのですが、以下の通りコードを記述しても画像が表示されません。

```
<img alt="写真" scr="MovieClub.jpg">
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなた様か、解決方法をご教授くださればと思います

Comment: scr は src では？

Comment: AWSとか関係なくて、相対パスの概念も理解できてなさそうです…。

Comment: ソースコードは可能な限り写真ではなくてテキストで入力してください。より検索に引っかかりやすくして、皆さんの目に留まるようになれば回答がつきやすくなります。

Comment: CSS指定部分も `link` が `linl` になっているように見えます

Answer (score 1):

- `<img>` タグのプロパティで `scr=` となっていますが、正しい綴りは `src=` です。
- HTML と画像は別のフォルダに配置されているので、portfolio.html から該当の画像を指定するには
  **相対パス** を使って以下のような記述になるはずです。

  ```
  <img src="../photo/MovieClub.jpg" alt="写真">
  ```

その他にも綴りミスと思われる箇所が散見されるので、参考書等を見ながら正しい綴りを確認してみてください。

---

*この投稿はコメント欄における複数ユーザーからのアドバイスを元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*