# 画像が表示されない

Tags: html

現在テックアカデミーさんの教材でHTMLを学習しております。(10月19日からメンターの指導開始の為聞ける人がおりません。)

**発生している問題**

画像を表示したいのですが、出てきません。(AWS Cloud9使用)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**これまでに試した事**

1. imgやsrc、altが入力間違えていないか確認した。
2. ダウンロードをし直して再度プレビューしなおした。
   (1の方法.画像ファイルをデスクトップからフォルダーにドラッグ&ドロップ
   →2の方法.File開く、upload local files、その後ドラッグ&ドロップでもやった)
3. `"images_kitchen/logo.png"`で見本（テックさんの教材）も間違えてないが、画像ファイルのURLが`/images_kitchen/images_kitchen/logo.png`なのが気になる。
   (Web上で検索かけたが出てこない。)
4. webブラウザを一度全部閉じて再度開いたが変わらない。

皆様大変お手数おかけ致しますがご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 重複候補: [HTML で指定した画像が表示されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59028/3060)

Comment: 当該コードと、各ファイルの配置関係が把握出来るディレクトリ構造を、質問文へ追記していただけませんか？